# CMake not finding SDL - Windows

Tags: compilation, cmake, sdl, building, path-variables

I am trying to build a program that requires SDL. I have downloaded SDL for Windows so that I have a folder containing the include and lib suborders.

When I run CMake I get the following error:

```
Could NOT find SDL (missing: SDL_LIBRARY SDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

This is despite the fact that I have created two environment variables called SDL_LIBRARY and SDL_INCLUDE_DIR, pointing to the lib and include folders respectively.

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Definitely a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Try to set `SDLDIR` environment variable instead of `SDL_LIBRARY` and `SDL_INCLUDE_DIR`. According to `FindSDL` documentation (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindSDL.html), this would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the best method when find scripts don't work as expected is to [check their source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindSDL.cmake). Often you will identify the problem by just reading through the documentation at the top, but if that still doesn't work out, digging into the source is often the only thing that helps.

From the documentation alone you can see for instance, that CMake does only consider one environment variable `SDLDIR` for searching. `SDL_INCLUDE_DIR` and `SDL_LIBRARY` are the names of the CMake variables to hold the results of the find script. You can set them via the command line (or the `cmake-gui`), but I would advise against that, as it kind of undermines the purpose of using a find script in the first place.

Instead, verify that your directory structure corresponds to what the find script expects and simply set `SDLDIR` accordingly.

Please note that the script that currently ships with CMake does *not* work with the newer SDL2. If you are using SDL2, you will have to write your own script.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. It worked.

I want to note for anyone reading this in the future: at first I added the path variable to my user variables and that didn't work. Once I added the variable to my system path variables it worked.